# Problema ao arrastar componentes no Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tô começando a usar android studio hoje, essa caixa azul do lado do layout ta certo?

E sempre que arrasto componentes pra o meio, o button vai pra cima sozinho, mas a caixa de seleção do button continua no meio. Alguém sabe?

Comment: Dê uma olhada: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Eu nem manjo de inglês man, mas pelo que vi, tenho mudar a position eu mesmo?

Comment: Cara, se não conseguir, vai na parte de texto e muda o tipo para `RelativeLayout` ou `LinearLayout`, seria mais fácil pra você

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia !
Henrrique, neste caso isto está acontecendo porque você está utilizando o CoordinatorLayout, que veio por padrão quando você criou o projeto e a classe Main.
Se você é iniciante no desenvolvimento Android sugiro que comece utilizando os Layouts: RelativeLayout e LinearLayout por serem os mais simples e intuitivos.
O RelativeLayput é perfeito para o que você está tentando fazer, para utiliza-lo siga esses passos:

1. Click na aba Text que se encontra no canto inferior da janela do Print, ao Lado de Design;
2. Logo após cabeçalho do XML substitua todo o pacote do CoordinatorLayout(com.android. ... .CoordinatorLayout) por RelativeLayout;
3. Pronto, agora basta voltar para a aba de Design e arrastar e posicionar os componentes na tela conforme preferir;

O LinearLayout trabalha com a questão de ordenação, onde você pode definir a orientação (horizontal ou vertical) e os componentes serão alinhado sempre um após o outro sem esforço;
O ConstraintLayout veio com a versão 2.3 do AndroidStudio e funciona de forma parecida com o Relative, porém com mais enfase em portabilidade de telas, sugiro que você pesquisa algum tutorial de exemplo de utilização deste !
Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Não costumo utilizar o modo layout. Então eis minha solução:

1. mude para modo texto.
2. Mude o tipo de layout (por padrão vem como `ConstraintLayout`) para `LinearLayout`.
3. Insira a tag orientation = vertical abaixo das dimensões.
4. Insira a opção `layout_gravity = center` e seu botão estará centralizado.

E tem um problema de renderização em seu projeto. Exponha-o.